# Angular Material CheckBox two way binding

Tags: angular

I'm populating checkboxes with data from my api and pushing the selected options to an array on my form. I've achieved the desired results in a `POST` request, however I've written another page for the `PUT` request and can't seem to get the options on my checkbox to be checked, with the options I selected before. Here's the code

HTML

```html
<mat-list>
 <mat-list-item *ngFor="let delivery of delivery_modes">
   <mat-checkbox
     (change)="delivery_mode($event)" [value]="delivery">{{delivery}}</mat-checkbox>
 </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Component

```
  delivery_mode(event) {
    if(event.checked) {
      this.form.delivery_mode.push(event.source.value)
    } else {
      this.form.delivery_mode = this.form.delivery_mode.filter(item => item.valueOf() !== event.source.value);
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to somehow make sure the checkbox options are checked with the data I passed before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idetodospoca, You can use a [(ngModel)] always you give value to your options, and forget (change)

```
<mat-list [(ngModel)]="form.delivery_mode">
 <mat-list-item *ngFor="let delivery of delivery_modes">
   <mat-checkbox [value]="delivery">{{delivery}}</mat-checkbox>
 </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<!--just for check-->
{{form.delivery_mode|json}}
```

So, you has a variabe "selectedDeliveries" that is an array

```
//And you can do by code, e.g.
form.delivery_mode=['delivery1','delivery3']
```

See a simple example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-29scxv?file=app/list-selection-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to make use the same state in various pages of your application. To maintain the state you can either a service which will keep your state [i.e. in your example - model bound to the checkbox]. You can inject this service in your various components and bound the service data to your template. Your POST API will keep updating the service data. This is a simple approach which is quick and easy to implement.

Another approach could be to make use of NGRX store [https://ngrx.io/]. It is powerful and makes so easy to implement a complex application.